# Google Chrome Crashes "The instruction at 0x0000000067CB1514 referenced memory at 0x00000000E9E44D9B. The memory could not be read."

Tags: windows, google-chrome, memory, windows-10, crash

Google Chrome crashes often on my system. Sometimes it says "Cannot set allocations" and other times it shows "The instruction at 0x0000000067CB1514 referenced memory at 0x00000000E9E44D9B. The memory could not be read."

I noticed this usually happens when opening up to YouTube or Facebook. But it can happen other times too.

[image]

My computer specs:
Windows 10
32 gigs of ram
500gb SSD
Nvidia gtx880m

Only happens in chrome... Mozilla or IE work fine.. :(

**UPDATE:**

So today I open Chrome and go to check on this question and I get yet another error:

[image]

I also tried running the [Chrome Cleanup tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/thankyou.html?utm_expid=52618439-14.oD8aQNrdTeWIf3d3CWjvig.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fchrome%2Fcleanup-tool%2F). No luck.

EDIT: I generated a dump here:

```
Instant Online Crash Analysis, brought to you by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc.

Show DivPrimary Analysis

Crash Dump Analysis provided by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc. (http://www.osr.com)
Online Crash Dump Analysis Service
See http://www.osronline.com for more information
Windows 8 Version 10240 MP (8 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
kernel32.dll version: 10.0.10240.16384 (th1.150709-1700)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sun Oct 11 19:44:08.000 2015 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:02:06.000
  Kernel time: 0 days 0:00:03.000
  User time: 0 days 0:00:13.000
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\oca.ini, error 2
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\winxp\triage.ini, error 2
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\user.ini, error 2
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for chrome.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for chrome.exe
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\guids.ini, error 2
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2
*** The OS name list needs to be updated! Unknown Windows version: 10.0 ***

FAULTING_IP: 
chrome_6e130000+3bf8f2
6e4ef8f2 ff34b8          push    dword ptr [eax+edi*4]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 6e4ef8f2 (chrome_6e130000+0x003bf8f2)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 8deee641
Attempt to read from address 8deee641

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  8deee641

READ_ADDRESS:  8deee641 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
chrome_6e130000+3bf8f2
6e4ef8f2 ff34b8          push    dword ptr [eax+edi*4]

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000032c

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_POINTER_READ

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 6e4ef74b to 6e4ef8f2

STACK_TEXT:  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
001aef28 6e4ef74b 00000056 00000000 0756df28 chrome_6e130000+0x3bf8f2
001aef68 6e4ef46e 0756df28 6fa3447c 001af058 chrome_6e130000+0x3bf74b
001aef80 6e4edf97 0756df28 07961ea0 0756df28 chrome_6e130000+0x3bf46e
001af058 6e3b2bd2 6feed4c0 0c31ef58 00000004 chrome_6e130000+0x3bdf97
001af380 6e4e5259 0c31ef58 0c31ef58 07675958 chrome_6e130000+0x282bd2
001af3b8 6e4dab6f 6e4da733 0c31ef58 07675958 chrome_6e130000+0x3b5259
001af3d4 6e4da9a2 128ce550 6e4da733 06c18798 chrome_6e130000+0x3aab6f
001af434 6e4da65a 128ce550 001af590 00000000 chrome_6e130000+0x3aa9a2
001af454 6e177e51 128ce530 001af590 02682f00 chrome_6e130000+0x3aa65a
001af53c 6e177b23 00000000 00000038 001af590 chrome_6e130000+0x47e51
001af574 6e177567 001af590 02662fc8 02662fc0 chrome_6e130000+0x47b23
001af6a8 6e231eb7 00000000 02662fc0 00000000 chrome_6e130000+0x47567
001af6c4 6e177043 00216230 02682f00 02682f00 chrome_6e130000+0x101eb7
001af6e4 6e176f4c 02682f00 00216230 001af744 chrome_6e130000+0x47043
001af708 6e176e54 6feed4ad 6feed4ad 015f7638 chrome_6e130000+0x46f4c
001af730 6e43fa4f 6f92af25 00216118 6fa644a8 chrome_6e130000+0x46e54
001af778 6e43f98e 00216128 ffffffff 02669410 chrome_6e130000+0x30fa4f
001af79c 6e150733 0029b030 00000000 002a1450 chrome_6e130000+0x30f98e
001af7cc 6e150571 001af7fc 002cb720 00000000 chrome_6e130000+0x20733
001af7e0 6e1504ed 001af810 001af7fc 001af854 chrome_6e130000+0x20571
001af82c 6e137671 00000000 002f3b60 001af87c chrome_6e130000+0x204ed
001af83c 6e136832 001af86c 00c87bea 00cc52b0 chrome_6e130000+0x7671
001af87c 00c6958c 00c40000 001af898 00c8cee4 chrome_6e130000+0x6832
001af95c 00c68a7c 00c40000 00000001 00000000 chrome+0x2958c
001afa54 00c8ce6a 00c40000 00000000 00211f06 chrome+0x28a7c
001afaa0 75923744 fe35e000 75923720 6f1cd5d9 chrome+0x4ce6a
001afab4 7753a064 fe35e000 ecf34ab8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
001afafc 7753a02f ffffffff 7755d7b0 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
001afb0c 00000000 00c8cee4 fe35e000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  chrome_6e130000+3bf8f2

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: chrome_6e130000

IMAGE_NAME:  chrome.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  56033dd8

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_chrome.dll!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_chrome_6e130000+3bf8f2

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/chrome_exe/45_0_2454_101/56034380/chrome_dll/45_0_2454_101/56033dd8/c0000005/003bf8f2.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
---------


This free analysis is provided by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc.
Want a deeper understanding of crash dump analysis? Check out our Windows Kernel Debugging and Crash Dump Analysis Seminar (opens in new tab/window)
Show DivLoaded Module List

Show DivRaw Stack Contents

Show DivDump Header Information

Show DivStrings
```

More details on stackdump

```
=================================================
Stack Trace: For the Crash ID - b56d2a222d37b962
=================================================

Thread 0 CRASHED [EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ @ 0xffffffff8deee800 ] MAGIC SIGNATURE THREAD
0x6e4ef8f2      (chrome.dll -rolling_time_delta_history.cc:21 ) cc::RollingTimeDeltaHistory::InsertSample(base::TimeDelta)
0x6e4ef74a      (chrome.dll -compositor_timing_history.cc:112 ) cc::CompositorTimingHistory::DidCommit()
0x6e4ef46d      (chrome.dll -single_thread_proxy.cc:294 )       cc::SingleThreadProxy::CommitComplete()
0x6e4edf96      (chrome.dll -layer_tree_host_impl.cc:1958 )     cc::LayerTreeHostImpl::ActivateSyncTree()
0x6e3b2bd1      (chrome.dll -scheduler.cc:659 ) cc::Scheduler::ProcessScheduledActions()
0x6e4e5258      (chrome.dll -scheduler.cc:219 ) cc::Scheduler::NotifyReadyToCommit()
0x6e4dab6e      (chrome.dll -single_thread_proxy.cc:853 )       cc::SingleThreadProxy::DoBeginMainFrame(cc::BeginFrameArgs const &)
0x6e4da9a1      (chrome.dll -single_thread_proxy.cc:833 )       cc::SingleThreadProxy::BeginMainFrame(cc::BeginFrameArgs const &)
0x6e4da659      (chrome.dll -bind_internal.h:346 )      base::internal::Invoker<base::IndexSequence<0,1>,base::internal::BindState<base::internal::RunnableAdapter<void ( cc::SingleThreadProxy::*)(cc::BeginFrameArgs const &)>,void ,base::internal::TypeList<base::WeakPtr<cc::SingleThreadProxy>,cc::BeginFrameArgs> 
,base::internal::TypeList<base::internal::UnwrapTraits<base::WeakPtr<cc::SingleThreadProxy> ,base::internal::UnwrapTraits<cc::BeginFrameArgs> ,base::internal::InvokeHelper<1,void,base::internal::RunnableAdapter<void 
( cc::SingleThreadProxy::*)(cc::BeginFrameArgs const &)>,base::internal::TypeList<base::WeakPtr<cc::SingleThreadProxy> const &,cc::BeginFrameArgs const &> >,void >::Run(base::internal::BindStateBase *)
0x6e177e50      (chrome.dll -task_annotator.cc:62 )     base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask(char const *,char const *,base::PendingTask const &)
0x6e177b22      (chrome.dll -message_loop.cc:473 )      base::MessageLoop::RunTask(base::PendingTask const &)
0x6e177566      (chrome.dll -message_loop.cc:594 )      base::MessageLoop::DoWork()
0x6e231eb6      (chrome.dll -message_pump_win.cc:184 )  base::MessagePumpForUI::DoRunLoop()
0x6e177042      (chrome.dll -message_pump_win.cc:57 )   base::MessagePumpWin::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate *)
0x6e176f4b      (chrome.dll -message_loop.cc:438 )      base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()
0x6e176e53      (chrome.dll -run_loop.cc:55 )   base::RunLoop::Run()
0x6e43fa4e      (chrome.dll -chrome_browser_main.cc:1709 )      ChromeBrowserMainParts::MainMessageLoopRun(int *)
0x6e43f98d      (chrome.dll -browser_main_loop.cc:877 ) content::BrowserMainLoop::RunMainMessageLoopParts()
0x6e43f952      (chrome.dll -browser_main_runner.cc:211 )       content::BrowserMainRunnerImpl::Run()
0x6e150732      (chrome.dll -browser_main.cc:26 )       content::BrowserMain(content::MainFunctionParams const &)
0x6e150570      (chrome.dll -content_main_runner.cc:384 )       content::RunNamedProcessTypeMain(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> 
const &,content::MainFunctionParams const &,content::ContentMainDelegate 
*)
0x6e1504ec      (chrome.dll -content_main_runner.cc:808 )       content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
0x6e137670      (chrome.dll -content_main.cc:19 )       content::ContentMain(content::ContentMainParams const &)
0x6e136831      (chrome.dll -chrome_main.cc:66 )        ChromeMain
0x00c6958b      (chrome.exe -client_util.cc:252 )       MainDllLoader::Launch(HINSTANCE__ *)
0x00c68a7b      (chrome.exe -chrome_exe_main_win.cc:157 )       wWinMain
0x00c8ce69      (chrome.exe -crt0.c:251 )       __tmainCRTStartup
0x75923743      (kernel32.dll + 0x00013743 )    BaseThreadInitThunk
0x7753a063      (ntdll.dll + 0x0005a063 )       __RtlUserThreadStart
0x7753a02e      (ntdll.dll + 0x0005a02e )       _RtlUserThreadStart
```

EDIT: 
Link to .zip with dump file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8IQnsZbQdI_LV9ROWo2YTByVDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: capture a crash dump and share the zipped dmp file: http://pastebin.com/B0WDZK3d

Comment: @magicandre1981 Do I have to edit any of the files in that link or can I use them as-is? (I am not sure how to code .reg files)

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried it as is and when that .reg file is installed, i cannot navigate to any webpages in Chrome anymore... It won't load any pages. So I uninstalled it.

Comment: share the dump (compresses it first to reduce the size and upload the zip/RAR to OneDrive), I need to look at it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I edited the question with the dump that google support sent me back. Does that help?

Comment: Perhaps a file is corrupted. Have you tried clearing ALL data (cache, history, site pref's, etc) and uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome?

Comment: I nee the actual dmp file, no text

Comment: @magicandre1981 updated the question with link to zip file

Comment: this is just a minidump so I can't display the exception record data. Try this .reg file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ne097hbe8avupt6/WER_Chrome.reg?dl=1 to generate a full dump.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't an answer but what I did was I installed Chrome Canary and used that for a week or so. I didn't have any crashes. Upon further inspection, I found out that Canary was 64 bit and the Chrome I had was 32 bit. I think the 32 bit thing was screwing me up for whatever reason. I have since switched to 64 bit beta Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely sounds like a bug in Chrome. Or the binary file is corrupted or infected. Try also upgrading your software to the recent version.

If that's not the case, then the problem can be related to 3rd party applications, so please disable your antivirus (for testing) and any other similar software.

If this happens for other apps as well, this likely can be related to your hardware memory issues.